# btrfs with multi devices fails automount in fstab

Tags: 12.04, fstab, btrfs

I'm trying to automount btrfs  on 12.04-desktop-amd64.
During bootsplash, fstab failed to mount btrfs and asked skip or manually prepare.

On the rootshell, `btrfs device scan` and `mount -a` could automount properly.
It seems "btrfs device scan" was missing from bootstrap.

Where should I add the line to prepare bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

Add device=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1 etc to the mount options (e.g. subvol=@,device=/dev...) depending on what your actual btrfs partitions are to grub.cfg.

Note that update-grub will overwrite this. You can monkeypatch /etc/grub.d/10_linux.

Theoretically initrd should do a btrfs device scan, and I think I've already seen bugs open for this. At any rate once I have a cleaner solution I will double check.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and add:

```
btrfs
```

And then run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as the original question owner. And your correction didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Definitively not the best solution, but the first one that works for me is to simply add `mount -a` to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: That could be dangerous if you have other filesystems that you may not want to automount. Perhaps a better solution here would be to mount only the target filesystem you're experiencing issues with in `/etc/rc.local`.