# How to use UUIDs in fstab for configuring btrfs RAID1

Tags: raid, fstab, btrfs

This is similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155651/btrfs-with-multi-devices-fails-automount-in-fstab), but the solution there was to choose the disks using "device=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1", which is not as robust as using UUIDs.  I'm sure it can be done, but I can't find any examples/documentation using UUIDs for the individual disks.

The closest example I could find is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2215391), but that's using "by-id" `device=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HDS724040ALE640_PK1334PBG3GYHS` instead of UUID which I'd prefer.

Using that as a template, I tried `UUID=3d12bc7b-61b1-4dea-b78b-ef9a44a6b698       /media/btr0    btrfs device=/dev/disk/by-uuid/6dc5624c-2d54-4726-b2fa-a7a988d337a4,device=/dev/disk/by-uuid/b57f2240-fa2e-4516-9049-603d2c5029b5 0 0` but it didn't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that my system was saying "scanning for btrfs file systems" during boot, so I simplified my fstab entry to `UUID=3d12bc7b-61b1-4dea-b78b-ef9a44a6b698 /media/btr0 btrfs defaults 0 0` and that seems to work OK.

Comment: +1 Right. The devices of a multi-device btrfs filesystem have the same UUID. The option `device=` is needed only when `btrfs device scan` is not run before mounting, but the latest versions of Ubuntu do it in the initrd (it is that command that prints the message "Scanning for btrfs filesystems")